# Scraping flex-element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, flexbox

I am trying to scrape some tennis statistics starting from 01-01-2019.
For this I try to scrape the following webpage with selenium: https://www.sofascore.com/de/tennis/2019-01-01

When I click on the first match manually the container on the right side changes and shows the statistics.
This is what I want to access automatically.

When I try to click on the element with selenium it redirects me to another page.
Can anyone tell me why it is not just showing the same content as by manually clicking and how I can solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  
import time

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
url = 'https://www.sofascore.com/de/tennis/2019-01-01'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.close()`
```

Comment: Can you try replacing you `xpath` with `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-list-cell-target").click()`?

Comment: The click itself redirects to another page. I also tried to just open the page with chromedriver and then click the page manually. -> Redirection. I found a workaround for this. It works when I click on the match. In the next page I use "driver.back()" -> At the next click everythin works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Col-pm5mcz-')]//descendant::div[contains(@class, 'styles__StyledWidget-')]
```

and get the `innerHTML` of that using `get_attribute` method

**Code :**

```
url = "https://www.sofascore.com/de/tennis/2019-01-01"
driver.get(url)
xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
sleep(2)
details = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'Col-pm5mcz-')]//descendant::div[contains(@class, 'styles__StyledWidget-')]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(details)
```

The xpath that you are using is absolute xpath `/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div`

try to replace that with Relative xpath.

Comment: The click itself redirects to another page. I also tried to just open the page with chromedriver and then click the page manually. -> Redirection. I found a workaround for this. It works when I click on the match. In the next page I use "driver.back()" -> At the next click everythin works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__List']//following::div/a[contains(@class,'EventCellstyles__Link')]")

for e in tableRows:
    e.click()
    //You can add implicit wait here for the statics section to load
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[text()='Statistiken']").click()
```

Comment: The click itself redirects to another page. I also tried to just open the page with chromedriver and then click the page manually. -> Redirection. I found a workaround for this. It works when I click on the match. In the next page I use "driver.back()" -> At the next click everythin works fine.